# the difference between a4j ajax listener and action in ajax call.

Tags: ajax, ajax4jsf

Please help me to understand the difference between a4j ajax listener and action in ajax call.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="abc" value="abc">
    <a4j:ajax execute="@this"
     ***listener="#{myBean.update()}"** or action = "#{#{myBean.update()}"***
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('myPopup')}.show(); return false;" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `<a4j:ajax >` tags like below.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="abc" value="abc">
    execute="@this"
    action = "#{myBean.update()"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('myPopup')}.show(); return false;" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

then it work with action , however with `<a4j:ajax >` tags, action doesn't trigger the method in the bean while listener triggered.